# Why can't I get the content-encoding of popular websites like google?

Tags: java, http

Here is the code I use to get the content encoding, however it seems there is no content-encoding used by websites like yahoo and google. Which I means either my code is wrong or they actually don't use content-encoding, I seem to think it is the former. So I just want to know where I went wrong?

```
package com.java24hours;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.net.http.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ServerCheck{
static String[] sites = {"https://www.google.com","https://www.yahoo.com"}; 
public static void check() throws URISyntaxException,IOException,InterruptedException{
    for(String site: sites){
    System.out.println("\nSite: " + site);
    HttpClient browser = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    URI uri = new URI(site);
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(uri).build();
    HttpResponse<String> response = browser.send(request,HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
Optional<String> contenttype = response.headers().firstValue("Content-Type");
Optional<String> contentencoding = response.headers().firstValue("Content-Encoding");

if (contentencoding.isPresent()){
System.out.println("Content-Encoding: " + contentencoding.get());
}else{
System.out.println("Content-Encoding not found");
}
if (contenttype.isPresent()){
System.out.println("Content-Type: " + contenttype.get());
}else{
System.out.println("Content-Type not found");
}
}



}


public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException,IOException,InterruptedException{

ServerCheck.check();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Content-Encoding` is only used when the client allows it.

Since you didn't send header `Accept-Encoding` in the request, it means only the `identity` encoding is allowed, and since that is the default encoding, no `Content-Encoding` header is present in the response.

If you want compression, specify the header:

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(uri)
        .setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
        .build();
```

Comment: So because I did not specify the encoding i accept, the server assumes no encoding ?

Comment: @ABC123 [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.3) says: ***If no Accept-Encoding field is present in a request,** the server MAY assume that the client will accept any content coding. In this case, if "identity" is one of the available content-codings, **then the server SHOULD use the "identity" content-coding**, unless it has additional information that a different content-coding is meaningful to the client.*

Comment: So why don't i get a content-encoding from google, if it assumes i accept any content-encoding?

Comment: @ABC123: the server doesn't have to assume you can accept any encoding; the RFC only says MAY. And one that wants to serve public users, like google and yahoo, probably does not. Even if it did, the server almost always has identity _available_, so it SHOULD use that. Plus nowadays it's almost certain either the server or some frontend or offload box does compression on the fly, so the website itself doesn't really have _any_ content-encoding.